# External attendees added to a calendar invite are not invited to the subsequent Hangout

Tags: google-calendar, google-hangouts

When I make a Google Calendar event on a Google Apps business account, a Hangout link is automatically generated:

[image: picture of Google Calendar event hangout link]

When I invite people from outside the organization to the event, they appear in the event as normal:

[image]

However, when I look at the list of people invited to the Hangout, it doesn't include the external invitees, and says the Hangout is restricted only to people in my organization:

[image]

Later, when the external attendee tries to join the Hangout, it obviously fails since they are not authorized. Manually inviting the attendee from the Hangout, or making the Hangout public, will work.

Obviously, this is quite obnoxious. What's the right way to make Hangouts work in the Google Calendar workflow? Do I always have to open the Hangout and set it to public, or is there a more automatic method?